# Matplotlib y-axis ticks removed when using axhline

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem where the `yaxis` ticks gets removed when using `a0.axhline`. I want to draw a line at `y = 0` but also keep `yaxis` ticks. How to achieve this?

With axhline: 
[image: With axhline]

Without axhline:
[image: Without axhline]

code:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
f, a0 = plt.subplots(1,1)
a0.axhline(color='dimgray', y='0', alpha=0.3, linestyle='-- ')
a0.set_title("Revolutions Per Minute")
a0.plot (step['time'], step['RPM'], color='royalblue')
```

Answer (score 4):

You set the position of the line as a string, `ax.axhline(y='0', ...)`. This will lead to it being interpreted as a category; and because it is the only category on the axis, no further ticklabels are shown. Instead, use numbers:

```
ax.axhline(y=0, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `yticks` and `yticklables` manually:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
f, a0 = plt.subplots(1,1)
a0.axhline(color='dimgray', y='0', alpha=0.3, linestyle='-- ')
a0.set_yticks([1, 2, 3])
a0.set_yticklabels([1, 2, 3])
a0.set_title("Revolutions Per Minute")
a0.plot (step['time'], step['RPM'], color='royalblue')
```

Edit: You could also get them from the axis if you plot first and add the line afterwards.

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
f, a0 = plt.subplots(1,1)
a0.plot (step['time'], step['RPM'], color='royalblue')
yticks = a0.get_yticks()
a0.set_yticks(yticks)
a0.set_yticklabels(yticks)
a0.axhline(color='dimgray', y='0', alpha=0.3, linestyle='--')
a0.set_title("Revolutions Per Minute")
```